# react-admin TextInput's label is translated

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Please take a look at `users.js` code at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-f38gy

In the code:

```
<SimpleForm>
  {/* ==> OK: Label is translated (string 'User Name' in the picture below) */}
  <TextInput source="username" />
  ....
<SimpleForm>
```

However, when putting TextInput inside a `Grid`, its label is not get translated.

```
<SimpleForm>
  <Grid container spacing={8}>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      {/* Issue: Label is NOT translated (string 'Username' in the picture below) */}
      <TextInput source="username" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</SimpleForm>
```

My question is why the second TextInput's label is not get translated?

[image: TextInput]

Comment: The second TextInput element did not receive the following parameters: className, resource, isRequired. They got the parent element of the Grid.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the direct answer to the question (perhaps the comment by @MaxAlex sheds some light on the answer).

If you simply want to rename the column of a field in react-admin, use the `label` prop:

```js
<TextInput source="username" label="User Name or whatever you want" />
```